# Android Lollipop WebView does not show <iframe> content

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I receive from the server xhtml code which I want to show in Android app like ebook reader. For this the [Monocle](https://github.com/joseph/Monocle) library was chosen.

Next I prepare webview with follow code:

```
contentView.addJavascriptInterface(new LectureJSInterface(), "Android");
contentView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
contentView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
contentView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFECECEC);
contentView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
contentView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Global.dismissProgressDialog();
    }
});
```

After this I download the xhtml code from the server and add to it JS code for working with Monocle:

```
private String prepareCode(String code) {
    if ((code == null) || code.equals("")) return "";

    String newCode = code.substring(code.indexOf("<html"), code.indexOf("<head>")+6);
    newCode = newCode.concat(
            "<script src=\"file:///android_asset/monocore.js\"></script>\n" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/monocore.css\" />\n" +
            "<style>\n" +
            "  #reader {\n" +
            "    width: 100%;\n" +
            "    height: 100%;\n" +
            "    border: 0px solid #000;\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "</style>\n" +
            "<script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  var isNightMode = false;\n" +
            "  var isFirstLoading = false;\n" +
            "  var startPageNumber = 1;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function setSettingsForFirstLoading(fontSize, pageNumber, nightMode) {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('setSettingsForFirstLoading()');\n" +
            "    isFirstLoading = true;\n" +
            "    isNightMode = nightMode;\n" +
            "    startPageNumber = pageNumber;\n" +
            "    window.changeFontSize(fontSize);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function changeFontSize(fontSize) {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('changeFontSize()');\n" +
            "    window.reader.formatting.setFontScale(fontSize);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function nightModeOn() {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('nightModeOn()');\n" +
            "    isNightMode = true;\n" +
            "    var i = 0;\n" +
            "    var frame;\n" +
            "    while (frame = window.reader.dom.find('component', i++)) {\n" +
            "      frame.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#1F1F1F';\n" +
            "      frame.contentDocument.body.style.color = '#ECECEC';\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function nightModeOff() {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('nightModeOff()');\n" +
            "    isNightMode = false;\n" +
            "    var i = 0;\n" +
            "    var frame;\n" +
            "    while (frame = window.reader.dom.find('component', i++)) {\n" +
            "      frame.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ECECEC';\n" +
            "      frame.contentDocument.body.style.color = '#1F1F1F';\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function turnPage(pageNumber) {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('turnPage(' + pageNumber + ')');\n" +
            "    window.reader.moveTo({ page: pageNumber });\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function savePercents() {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('savePercents()');\n" +
            "    Android.savePercents(window.reader.getPlace().percentAtTopOfPage());\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function moveToPercents(percent) {\n" +
            "    Android.printLogInfo('moveToPercents(' + percent + ')');\n" +
            "    turnPage(window.reader.getPlace().pageAtPercentageThrough(percent));\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function listenFor(evtName) {\n" +
            "    Monocle.Events.listen('reader', evtName, report);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function report(evt) {\n" +
            "    switch (evt.type) {\n" +
            "    case 'monocle:loaded':\n" +
            "        Android.calculateSeekBar(window.reader.getPlace().properties.component.lastPageNumber());\n" +
            "        break;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    case 'monocle:turn':\n" +
            "        Android.updatePagesCounter(window.reader.getPlace().pageNumber());\n" +
            "        break;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    case 'monocle:recalculated':\n" +
            "        if (isNightMode) nightModeOn();\n" +
            "        if (isFirstLoading) { isFirstLoading = false; turnPage(startPageNumber); }\n" +
            "        Android.calculateSeekBar(window.reader.getPlace().properties.component.lastPageNumber());\n" +
            "        Android.updatePagesCounter(window.reader.getPlace().pageNumber());\n" +
            "        break;\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  function init() {\n" +
            "    var options = {\n" +
            "      flipper: Monocle.Flippers.Slider\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    listenFor('monocle:turn');\n" +
            "    listenFor('monocle:loaded');\n" +
            "    listenFor('monocle:recalculated');\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    window.reader = Monocle.Reader('reader', null, options);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  Monocle.Events.listen(window, 'load', init);\n" +
            "</script>\n");
    newCode = newCode.concat(code.substring(code.indexOf("<head>") + 6, code.indexOf("<body>") + 6));
    newCode = newCode.concat("<div id=\"reader\">");
    newCode = newCode.concat(code.substring(code.indexOf("<body>") + 6, code.indexOf("</body>")));
    newCode = newCode.concat("</div>");
    newCode = newCode.concat(code.substring(code.indexOf("</body>")));
    return newCode;
}
```

After finishing this task the WebView loads it:

```
contentView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, prepareCode(code), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

What I have as results? I tested this app on six devices with Android 4.x and 5.x. On Android 4.x the entire content is shown correctly, but on Android 5.x I see a blank page. I should notice that the xhtml code was loaded because I can call JS-functions and get its results via JS Interface.

Are there any ideas about ways to fixing this bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Android Lollipop WebView does not show <iframe> content" -- um, there's no `<iframe>` in your code.

Comment: Monocle uses `<iframe>` in its code. It inserts `<div id="reader">content</div>` into `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: And what exactly is `content`?

Comment: `content` is any xhtml code which is returned from the server. It's the whole code between `<body>` and `</body>` as I've explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling the webview system update.

or

Try monocle 2.3.1

or

https://github.com/joseph/Monocle/issues/259

Comment: I tried to change `Monocle.Styles.affix(ce, "transform", "translateX(-"+offset+"px)");` to `Monocle.Styles.setX(ce, offset);` in the function `translateToOffset(offset, transition)` but it didn't help.

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/joseph/Monocle/issues/259#issuecomment-127471417 But I'm not sure that this is a right way.